# Re-open SqlDataReader 

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, exception, sqldatareader

My code throws the error

> Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

I'm using SqlDataReader to read values from database, and that is my code:

```
while (rd.Read())
{
    string stateincharge = rd["stateincharge"].ToString();
    string email = rd["email"].ToString();
    cmd.Dispose();
    rd.Close();
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "str_procedure";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stateincharge", stateincharge);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
    ad.Fill(ds);
    count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
}
```

This runs in a loop in ASP.NET code-behind.

My problem is that I think I need to close SqlDatReader because of an error shown.

How can I again open sqlDataReader at end of the while loop?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? I think you're understanding is mixed up. And if you could please explain maybe we could point out a better way of doing it.

Comment: at which line do you receive 'close DataReader first error'?

Comment: Can you put the code that whole code because i think you are doing something wrong with the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the line that closes the reader `rd.Close();` because you are closing the reader inside the while loop then you try to access the reader again. Also, I think if you used a new SQL command and new adapter you will not receive this error.

Comment: using new connection for adapter

Answer (score 2):

```
// connection for reader
using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command1 = new connection1.CreateCommand())
{
    command1.CommandText = commandText1;

    connection1.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // fill table in loop
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string stateincharge = reader["stateincharge"].ToString();
            string email = reader["email"].ToString();

            // connection for adapter
            using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command2 = new connection2.CreateCommand())
            {
                command2.CommandText = commandText2;

                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stateincharge", stateincharge);
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email ", email );

                connection2.Open();

                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                using (SqlDataApapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command2))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(table);
                    // yield return table;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each connection can have at most one active command (which includes the "response", that is, the reader). You're trying to do a nested call to the DB and this requires that you either load the data completely (for instance into a `DataTable`) before looping, or that you uise a second connection for the nested calls to `str_procedure`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (rd.Read())
    {
        string stateincharge = rd["stateincharge"].ToString();
        string email = rd["email"].ToString();
        cmd.Dispose();
        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "str_procedure";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stateincharge", stateincharge);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
        ad.Fill(ds);
        count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
}
rd.Close();
```

Comment: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.